# What is the difference between buck and step-down converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, led-driver, step-down

I always thought "buck" and "step-down" are synonyms. But now I'm looking at two datasheets:

- [CAT4201](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/cat4201-d.pdf)
- [CAV4201](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/cav4201-d.pdf)

They seem very similar, but the first is described as "350 mA High Efficiency Step Down LED Driver", the second as "LED Driver, 350 mA, Step-Down Converter".

Though, most of the pages of the datasheet are identical.

What is the difference between the two drivers?

Comment: It looks to me like the CAT4201 is a more efficient one then, if it's called a high-efficiency one and the other isn't.

Comment: @Hearth, it seems to me a marketing call. See Figure 12 of both: are identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're the same, it's just a matter of terminology and whoever happened to write the datasheet at the time.

The difference between those two components is that the CAV is automotive AEC and PPAP qualified, while the CAT is not, which explains the price difference.